# Android Spreadsheet data into ArrayList HashMap populate ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I have a public google spreadsheet that I am pulling data from and loading into an  **ArrayList < HashMap < String, String > >**

then I am trying to populate it into a custom ListView.

Essentially my spreadsheet has just 3 columns "Timestamp" "question1" and "question2". I am assuming the keys for the hashmaps should all be the same, only the value would change?

I am using a custom ArrayAdapter with a custom xml layout  with three TextViews. In my getView() I've been trying to iterate through the HashMap and populate the listview. I can't seem to get this to work. When I run, it only shows me the very last cell.

This is the code I am using to pull individual Rows from the spread sheet and put it into a HashMap:

```
            // Print entries
            for(ListEntry row : feed.getEntries())
            {

            //Print the first column's cell value
                System.out.println("new row");

              for(String i : row.getCustomElements().getTags())
              {

                    System.out.println("     "+i + ": " + row.getCustomElements().getValue(i));

                    rowMap.put(row.getCustomElements().getValue("question1"), 
                            row.getCustomElements().getValue(i));

                    pulledData2.add( (HashMap<String, String>) rowMap );                                

              } 
            }
```

**List Adapter , getView()**

```
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mItems = pulledData2;
        public ListAdapter(DashboardActivity dashboardActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items, LayoutInflater inflater){

            super(dashboardActivity, -1, items);
            this.mItems = items;    
    }       

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        //inflate the custom view
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                    DashboardActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, parent, false);
        }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTimeStamp))
                                .setText( mItems.get(position).get("question1"));
```

Comment: better to use model class with getter setter method

Comment: please, could you explain or direct me towards an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so my problem was that I wasn't instantiating a new hashMap everytime a row was being pulled. I added a while loop and I now have unqiue HashMaps

```
                        while( i <= pulledData.size()) {

                            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            item.put(tag, row.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));

                            //pulledData.add(entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
                            pulledData2.add(i, item);   
                            i++;
                        }
```